# Bad user experience in documentation version diffs

Tags: feature-request, documentation, user-experience

**Goal**: Get the raw markdown of a version or rollback to it.

As we're used to, we click on the "Edited" link to see the history.

We're now offered two buttons for each version, *View Edit* and *View Topic*.

Nothing is telling me where to go for rolling back… trying the first button… *View Edit*. Nothing there, not even raw markdown to copy from. Just the diff. hmmm.

Next try *View Topic*. A full view of the old version here. With a link to roll back. Okay, while this is well hidden, we found it.

How do we get the raw markdown?

> I can click on create a draft … but the text scared the hell out of me for a minute that it'll actually create a suggestion, until I realized it's only a draft.

Good, let's now try the actual rollback.

`976 characters deleted`?? Why did so much change in the rollback? … Well, turns out the penultimate version on the particular example was actually not the one with the penultimate version *on the topic* in general.

Thus, we first need to search between all the examples the one with the penultimate version, before we can actually successfully rollback. Ugh.

Please, improve this user experience, it's horrible and scary to find it.

Comment: Related to this problem, edits to examples are treated as edits of the overall topic, so two independent edits by the same user to different examples can only be approved or rejected together.  There's no way to approve one of the example edits and reject the other (or even just abstain)

Comment: @RGA not directly related… But there really should be an option to _split_ somebodys diff into two parts which can be approved/rejected independently.

Comment: Certainly agree, although the logistics of how you would do this might be complicated (hence why i suggest dividing only by example).  Otherwise, we could be stuck having to approve each character on its own

Comment: @RGA yes, per example. But then it should be independent edits for the system too. If we retain it in one same edit, it gets an UX nightmare (again).

Comment: It seems the past week has been nothing but UX/UI Nightmares....