# Discarding not accounted for in draft creation limit

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

I've attempted to do an edit, but was greeted with:

> You've already created the maximum of 50 example drafts today. Please come back tomorrow to continue creating examples.

I've only submitted 3 changes today. I've discarded a number of drafts, but I cannot imagine it were 50 drafts.

I maybe have clicked the edit *symbol* (that tiny icon) a 50 times, including the times where I already had an active draft.

I believe there is something horribly wrong in the draft counting. And draft discarding must reduce the count also. [Especially if nothing has been changed / the draft never submitted as change proposal.]

You quickly amount for a lot of drafts when searching the penultimate version of a topic with many examples for rollbacking. (See also [Bad user experience in documentation version diffs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328746/bad-user-experience-in-documentation-version-diffs))

Or simply looking at the raw markdown for an example (without changing anything), seems to also increase your draft count. Looks broken...

Comment: I don't really understand. My limit is 10 drafts creation (not per day, globally I think) and my drafts are not reviewed. How is this limit calculated? Where I find more info? I couldn't post anything new in documentation the past days. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I've never reached the global limit, so I do not know. You'll have to ask a separate meta question.