# Fighting with the editing interface (or: Show me what I requested to see)

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

I find myself fighting with the editor interface a lot. I like to open the current iteration of the topic in a seperate tab besides the edit proposal I am currently working on. However, when you have a current draft, it will open a topic in editing mode, regardless what link I seem to click. Luckily for me, if I discard the draft there I go back to the original topic.

However, I just rolled back an edit on 1 example, which inconveniently rolled back the same edit on different examples too, and I did not notice this because of unresponsive scripts. I submitted the edit, then noticed that it rolled back too much. There is however no way to get back the original edit. Retracting the edit will cause the editor to show up again, but cancelling this edit will put the edit back in the queue. I can't get back to the original version to copy over the markup of the original version. I can't copy the diff from the edit proposal, because it copies the markup of the new version too. I can't discard the retracted edit to get back to the original version. I can't just press a button "undo my changes on this example and reset to the current version".

The whole process is frustrating. When I click a link I expect to end up at that same view of the same topic every time, not at an "intelligent" guess of what I want to see.

Comment: And if you do that too often, then this happens: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329625/discarding-not-accounted-for-in-draft-creation-limit :-(

Comment: Not just the editor, the whole UI of Documentation has been a big disappointment. Not just because it's new but because critical functionality is either missing, broken or awkward and a lot of it is not very intuitive. Seems like it was released long before it was ready for prime time